# Dynamic view binding using DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, light

`<DataTemplate DataType="{Binding GetViewModel}"  Resources="{Binding GetView}">
            <!--<vw:SomeView/>-->
        </DataTemplate>`

I am trying to bind view dynamically in code of MainViewModel linked to above MainView's code.
How can I bind datatype and vw:SomeView dynamically?

Comment: Is this for Silverlight or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTemplate.DataType property is not a dependency property so you cannot bind to its values:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx

Typically you will have multiple DataTemplate instances define in your XAML which describe how your UI renders each view model. The framework then takes care of using these DataTemplates when a control tries to render a view model of that type.